# Create list of words and group them by index

Tags: python, pandas, list, group-by, aggregation-framework

I have column of index and each index has it's corresponding word:

| id | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | word1 |
| 1 | word2 |
| 1 | word3 |
| 2 | word4 |
| 2 | word5 |

and so on.

I want to group them by index in this way:
for id 1-[word1,word2,word3]
for id 2-[word4,word5]

and so on

and extract to CSV file

I have this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
d={"word":"first"}
df_new = df.groupby(df['id'], as_index=False).aggregate(d).reindex(columns=df['word'])
print (df_new)

df_new.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

What do I need to change in order for that to work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you want to merge all `word` entries with a particular `id` into a single row?

Comment: yes and I have 7000 rows of index with words

Comment: Try `df.groupby("id").agg(list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Import Dependencies
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'word': ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Groupby and Merge
df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'word' : ','.join})
```

```
# Result

    id  word
0   1   word1,word2,word3
1   2   word4,word5
```

Comment: It helps, but should I do if I have 7000 rows of index and their words?

Comment: Have you tried my answer on your 7000 row dataset? Are you facing any issues with it?

Comment: it works but not when I extract the SCV file for some reason

Comment: Post a screenshot of the issue in your question